# Support for Windows-Left and Windows-Right in undecorated JFrames

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I use an undecorated JFrame with a custom title bar and custom resizer. All works fine but when I make a JFrame undecorated I lose the support for Windows-Left/Right key bindings (seems that it's native implemented by Windows). I want to reimplement this feature for my application. My problem: I can detect in a key listener whether the Windows key pressed, but I cannot detect whether another key (left/right in my case) is pressed together with Windows key (no modifier WINDOWS_MASK_DOWN in InputEvent). Probably somebody knows a workaround?

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class HeadlessFrameTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test");
        final JTextField field = new JTextField();
        frm.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        field.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });
        frm.setUndecorated(true);
        frm.setSize(500, 550);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 `(no modifier WINDOWS_MASK_DOWN in InputEvent).` No event is even generated when the right/left key is pressed (in JDK7), although an event is generated for the keyReleased event. This tells me that Windows is intercepting the event. It is strange that the right/left key functionality doesn't work because the Windows+Up key does maximize the window, although the Windows+Down does not restore the window. So there definitely are inconsistencies. I don't know the solution.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same issue and I'm looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I couldn’t test it properly as on my system, <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> *were* intercepted and processed by Windows even for undecorated frames, however adding another case for the unused combination <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> proved that the following code works if the host system does not consume the key shortcut:

(Update: since it seems to be the key pressed event which Windows consumes, a key release of <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> or <kbd>Right</kbd> can be catched)

```
final JFrame frm = new JFrame("Test");
final JTextField field = new JTextField();
frm.add(field, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frm.getToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
    boolean winDown;
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        KeyEvent ev=(KeyEvent)event;
        final boolean pressed = ev.getID()==KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED;
        if(ev.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS) winDown=pressed;
        else if(winDown) switch(ev.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                System.out.println("windows + LEFT "+(pressed?"pressed":"released"));
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                System.out.println("windows + RIGHT "+(pressed?"pressed":"released"));
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_A:
                System.out.println("windows + A "+(pressed?"pressed":"released"));
                break;
        }
    }
}, KeyEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
frm.setUndecorated(true);
frm.setSize(500, 550);
frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frm.setVisible(true);
```

It seems that an ordinary key listener on a component does not work because the component loses the focus when <kbd>Windows</kbd> is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your suggestion don't work (at least on my Windows computer).

Comment: Does not work regarding `win+arrow` or even for `win + A`? I’m afraid, windows is intercepting the `win+arrow` keycombos even if they don’t work. But `win + A` did work on my machine, win7 and both jdk7 and jdk8. Therefore, I’m afraid that’s the closest thing you can get, in other words, if that doesn’t work, there will be no solution.

Comment: Windows+A works, but my goal is Windows+ArrowLeft/Right because users know these keys.

Comment: Ok, I updated the code to react on key release as well. If you can live with your program reacting when the left/right key has been released, you have a solution. Otherwise, there’s nothing we can do (besides filing a feature request to Oracle). Maybe the *real question* is why win+left and win+right don’t work?

Comment: Yeah. That's the question. I'll post a RFE for AWT. Probably can Oracle implement it.